# AWS S3: Credentials missing (aws-sdk v3)

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to replace S3 `aws-sdk` v2 with `@aws-sdk/client-s3` v3 (The [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html) I am using). This was working with v2 (putObject, getObject, etc.), but with the changes, I am getting an error saying:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Credentialis missing
> Error: Credentialis missing

This error happens upon load, I am not even calling any of the methods, just initializing the S3 object.

```js
  private readonly s3 = new S3({
    region: environment.AWS.region,
    credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
      client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: environment.AWS.region }),
      identityPoolId: environment.AWS.identityPoolId
    })
  })
```

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug in the sdk https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1798. I added my comment there...

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because **CognitoIdentityClient** is expecting credentials even though they're not required.

```
private readonly s3 = new S3({
    region: environment.AWS.region,
    credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
      client: new CognitoIdentityClient({
        region: environment.AWS.region,
        credentials: () => Promise.resolve({} as any), // Temporary fix for problem
      }),
      identityPoolId: environment.AWS.identityPoolId
    })
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have the files `C:\Users\<user>\.aws\config` and `C:\Users\<user>\.aws\credentials`.
The config file should be like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
aws_secret_access_key=ab2sjemdoKDFEJ9?SJDjddd
region=us-west-1
```

And the credentials file should be like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
aws_secret_access_key=ab2sjemdoKDFEJ9?SJDjddd
```

Comment: The folder location on Windows is actually c:\users\<username>\.aws\ or, better yet, %USERPROFILE%\.aws\. On non-Windows OS, it's ~/.aws/

Comment: Oh yes sorry my mistake, ill fix it

Comment: The fix for this is to add `credentials: () => Promise.resolve({} as any)` to `new CognitoIdentityClient` as mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1798#issuecomment-748670230)